# .htaccess headache with perl script?

Tags: perl, .htaccess

Trying to get a simple test perl script working. Have the following files/folder structure on a shared hosting service:

**~/public_html/**

- .htaccess

**~/public_html/lookup**               Permissions: "drwxrwxrwx  2 myusername myusername"

- .htaccess
- lookup.pl*              Permissions: "-rwxr-xr-x    myusername  myusername"

The first .htaccess contains:

```
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(r)$ $1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^(r)/(.*)(\.[a-z]+)$ redirect.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(r)/(.*)$ redirect.php?$1 [L]
```

The second .htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lookup

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lookup/lookup.pl [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|png|jpg|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ lookup.pl/$1 [QSA,NC]
```

But direct access to: www.mysite.com/lookup/lookup.pl does not work and shows a "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: What your error_log tells you about the lookup.pl error ?

Comment: [Wed Jul 07 TIME] [error] [client IPADDRESS] File does not exist: /home/myusername/public_html/500.shtml

Comment: Are there any more error log entries before the one you have posted? That error message means that a custom error response page could not be found. That's an error related to displaying the error... :-)

Comment: What do you get when you execute the perl script from the command line? Does it send the correct headers?

Comment: Yup! Just two lines...

#!/usr/bin/perl use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a rough guess, because I don't know your complete configuration: Are you running the site under suEXEC (having a `VirtualHost` with `User` or `Group` directives in it)?

In that case you cannot run the script because the directory it's stored in is world-writable, which suEXEC does not like, and no error message is shown in the error_log (as Mike pointed out, the error message you provided does not relate to the real error, but to an error presenting a correct error page to you), but in the suexec_log which most people normally do not consult.

Comment: In that case you are _likely_ running under suEXEC because that's more or less a standard for running CGI in shared hosting. Please fix the permissions of the "lookup" directory from 777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 755 (rwxr-xr-x).

Comment: Shoot me... the error was because these were actually TWO lines (but should have been THREE)... (LINE1)#!/usr/bin/perl use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); (LINE2)print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

Comment: I'll accept your answer as you really did try to help me out here!